# Erlang beam_lib chunks is broken?

Tags: erlang, elixir, beam, erlang-escript

I've tried to decompile .beam file (compiled from elixir code)

I used this escript

```
main([BeamFile]) ->
    {ok,{_,[{abstract_code,{_,AC}}]}} = beam_lib:chunks(BeamFile,[abstract_code]),
    io:fwrite("~s~n", [erl_prettypr:format(erl_syntax:form_list(AC))]).
```

Which generated a file. But on compiling this code again I get error on '-spec' annotation

```
lib/renlim.erl:7: syntax error before: '{'
```

The code is unchanged. Is it related to new Erlang version or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Erlang spec Error]

Comment: Pretty sure it's the `erl_prettypr` pretty-printer that's broken, failing to turn the abstract format for the `spec` attribute back into proper Erlang source. Specifically, the `erl_syntax:attribute_arguments/1` function called by the pretty-printer does not appear to handle the `spec` attribute.